# Regular expressions - how to add whitespaces to a fixed amount of numbers?

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex for bank account number. As far i got this:

```
Regex(@"^([0-9]{26})$");
```

And this accepts only 26 numbers. I would like it to accept 26 numbers and infinite amount of whitespaces, so that user can format this string whatever he wants to. How can i to that?

Comment: Filter out all whitespaces (or even all non-numeric characters) before checking against the regex.

Comment: -1 you should specify the language you are using..regex implementation differs across languages...

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^\s*([0-9]\s*){26}$
```

Comment: This regex is invalid, if i put in 26 digits AND spaces, it crashes.

Comment: I've tested it at http://regexpal.com/ with test string " 2        32222 2  2       22222       222222       2223345". Try that

Comment: @ojek, this is valid for javascript, are you using something else ?

Comment: @Piyuesh: `\s` would also allow new line characters and the likes.